# RadiusNetworks iBeacon didRangeBeaconsInRegion return 0 beacons

Tags: ibeacon

I am trying to detect iBeacons with a specific UUID and Major. The didRangeBeaconsInRegion is being called but the Beacon collection it returns has 0 entries.

The below is my code (abridged a bit)

```
private static final String BEACON_UUID = "F8AD3E82-0D91-4D9B-B5C7-7324744B2026";
private static final int BEACON_MAJOR = 36582;

@Override
public void onIBeaconServiceConnect() {
    iBeaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<IBeacon> iBeacons, Region region) {
            if (iBeacons.size() > 0) {
                IBeacon thisBeacon = iBeacons.iterator().next();
            }
        }
    });

    try {
        iBeaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myUniqueID", BEACON_UUID, BEACON_MAJOR ,null));
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I am assuming I am doing my binding correctly as the didRangeBeaconsInRegion(..) is being called successfully.

I have used RadiusNetwork's own application to detected the beacons and that works fine and I can see them all so it is not seem to be an issue with Bluetooth on my device

Answer (score 2):

A couple of tips:

1. Double check that your BEACON_UUID and BEACON_MAJOR are correct for the beacon that is transmitting.  For testing, try setting both of these to null temporarily until you get it working, then you can set them back to the values you have.
2. It is normal for the iBeacons.size() to be zero *sometimes* if a beacon did not happen to be detected in a given cycle.  But it should not always be of size zero.  I'm not sure how you are testing, but try adding a `Log.d(TAG, "Number of beacons detected: "+iBeacons.size());` and let it run to see if you ever get a non-zero number.

Comment: I have a question about 'sometimes'. I use the current version of your library. On a Moto X 2gen (Lollipop), I observe this: out of 5 didRangeBeaconsInRegion calls, maybe 1 gets a beacon. The rest get 0 beacons. I use default values. On a HTC one (Lollipop), the same works very reliably. Interestingly, using a very old version of your library (> 2 years old) it also works reliably on the Moto 2X. Do you have any hints as to what might be causing this?

Comment: This sounds like a different problem.  I would try the Locate Beacon app on the problematic phone, then open a new question with the results of that test included, too.

Comment: Indeed the beacon is directly next to the phones when I tested this. I was hoping you'd just say "oh but it's obvious, just call manager.setMagicParameter() and everything will be fine!" :) I shall do more testing and open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to check the uuid , major and minor values of your beacons and make them match with the region u want.

didRangeBeaconsInRegion should return an array af beacons.

You can use the "beecon" app to update easily the values.

Hope this can help you.

Regards.